# Determine $\tan(α)$ in the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

In the figure below $ABCD$ is a square. Determine $\tan(α)$.

Alternatives:
$A)\, 0.9\\ 
B)\, 0.8\\
C)\, 0.7\\
D)\, 0.6\\
E)\, 0.5$

[image]

$FG=r\\
AB=BC=CD+AD = l\\
\triangle AHG: AH^2=(l+r)^2-(l-r)^2 \implies AH^2=4lr\\
\therefore AH = 2\sqrt{lr}$
$\tan \alpha = \frac{r}{CF}=\frac{r}{l-2\sqrt{lr}}$

???
[image]

Comment: (1) CG is not equal to r, if r is the radius of the smallest circle. (2) I guess you mean CD = AD. (3) the calculation will be simpler if we let l = 1. Then, after some calculation, r = 0.16.

Comment: Using the result $AH$, also consider the third constraint circle and the right-angled $\triangle EFG$.

Comment: @DavidK  thanks for alert, adjusted.

Comment: What is the justification for making the points F, G and I collinear?

Comment: @WW1 The dot for $I$ is not really centered on the line $FH,$ so I think it was an unintentional quirk of the diagram that it is near that line. The text of the question doesn't refer to it. I'm guessing the point was automatically labeled by Geogebra when one of the arcs was drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your work, we have $AH = 2 \sqrt r$ if we let $l = 1$.

Then, $CF = 1 – 2 \sqrt r$.

From $\triangle EGI$ [should be $ \triangle EFG$], we get $(0.5 – r)^2 = r^2 + (2 \sqrt r – 0.5)^2$

Then, $r = 0.16$. Result follows.

Comment: @DavidK Nice catch. Corrected.